# TextMate and Cucumber: Autocomplete (Opt-Esc) results in a Ruby error "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''"

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, cucumber, textmate

I'd really love to have steps auto completion in TextMate, but when having my cursor somewhere in a step and pressing Opt-Esc, it results in the following:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of filemap!'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of filespecs'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:137:in /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of filerequested_specs'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of filesetup'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:100:in /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of filerequire'
  from /Users/josh/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/Cucumber.tmbundle/Support/lib/cucumber/mate/feature_helper.rb:1
  from /tmp/temp_textmate.gE2STt:3:in
```

Anyone got this working? I'm on Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and the newest versions of Rails and Cucumber.